# Unable to access the radio button group from within the anonymous inner class

Tags: java, radio-button, radio-group

I am a beginning programmer. Posting a small portion of a GUI application I have created. The problem is that I want the group of Radio buttons and some text boxes to be clear when a button is clicked but the button group is not accessible from within the actionListener for the button. I understand the problem of scope very well but it is necessary to perform this action through the button. Please help me.

```
               ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
               bg.add(rbtn1);
               bg.add(rbtn2);
               bg.add(rbtn3);
               bg.add(rbtn4);

               JButton clrBtn= new JButton("Clear");
               clrBtn.setForeground(SystemColor.textHighlight);
               clrBtn.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18));
               clrBtn.setBounds(198, 353, 98, 36);
               frame.getContentPane().add(clrBtn);

               clrBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      
                      @Override
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                             String v = "";
                             textField.setText(v);
                             textField_1.setText(v);
                             textField_2.setText(v);
                             txtKdfj.setText(v);  
                        }
                 });
```

Comment: You can make the ButtonGroup variable final.

Comment: Ohhh.... Very easy solution. I wonder why didn't I think about it......